# Factorial of a large number in python

Tags: python, algorithm, factorial

Here's my approach to factorials:

```
def factorial(n):
    '''Returns factorial of n'''
    r = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        r *= i
    return r
```

I think it's pretty straightforward, though I guess you could make something more efficient, because it takes ages for large numbers like 100000. My question is, is there? math.factorial() is no good either, it takes roughly the same amount of time.

Comment: You can save some memory at least, if not time, by using xrange instead of range.  xrange is a generator, and doesn't need to allocate the entire list in advance.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Python 3, and range() is now a generator.

Comment: Also have you thought of using the built in `math.factorial`? It's a little bit faster than your code above.

Answer (score 26):

Multiplying the numbers in sequence,

```
r = 1
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    r *= i
return r
```

creates a large number (as in tens of thousands of bits) very quickly, and then you have a lot of multiplications of one huge number and one small number. Multiplications where at least one of the factors is huge are slow.

You can speed it up considerably by reducing the number of multiplications involving huge numbers, for example

```
def range_prod(lo,hi):
    if lo+1 < hi:
        mid = (hi+lo)//2
        return range_prod(lo,mid) * range_prod(mid+1,hi)
    if lo == hi:
        return lo
    return lo*hi

def treefactorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return range_prod(1,n)
```

produces, timing the computation of `100000! % 100019` (I first tried `len(str(fun(100000))`, but the conversion to string is abominably slow, so that made the difference seem smaller than it is):

```
$ python factorial.py 
81430
math.factorial took 4.06193709373 seconds
81430
factorial took 3.84716391563 seconds
81430
treefactorial took 0.344486951828 seconds
```

so a more than 10× speedup for `100000!`.

Comment: Are you ok with this being used in BSD-licensed SciPy?   https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6020

Comment: @endolith Sure. I don't take any responsibility for errors in the code, though. Nor can I claim any originality regarding the algorithm, it's old.

Comment: So this calculates 9! as `((2*3)*(4*5))*((6*7)*(8*9))`?  It might be better to use`((2*9)*(3*8))*((4*7)*(5*6))` to keep them smaller for longer?

Comment: @endolith That doesn't make much difference in terms of the size of the intermediate products. When I tested (long ago, in Haskell), I couldn't get that scheme to be faster than the above, since the code becomes more complicated. Do test, it might buy you a little, but don't expect too much from it.

Comment: Doesn't appear to make a difference in Python 3.7.8 for 1000000.

Answer (score 11):

Factorials get very large, so it is often better to deal with logarithms of the number.

Many languages have an **lgamma** library function which computes the natural logarithm of the factorial of n-1.

This means that you can compute the natural logarithm of factorial(n) via **lgamma(n+1)**.

You can divide by log10 to turn this into a base 10 logarithm.

So if you just want the number of digits, then this Python code will give the answer immediately:

```
from math import *
print ceil(lgamma(100000+1)/log(10))
```

Comment: `logamma` is in Python 2.7.x and in Python 3.2+ (but not in 3.0.x or 3.1.x).

Comment: Fun fact: looking at the sources, Python uses the Lanczos approximation for the gamma function (`Modules/mathmodules.c`).

Answer (score 7):

If you need a short execution time and don't need the best possible accuracy, you can use an approximation formula, e.g. [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Answer (score 3):

If you just need an approximation, Ramanujan's factorial approximation is supposed to be more accurate than Stirling's.

If you need (or want)  something precise, you might try GMP, the GNU Multiple Precision library.  I've used it successfully for primality testing of large numbers in Python.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually unusual to really need the true factorial value n! in many areas of application. Often it's way more realistic to use the natural log of the factorial. I can't think of any applications where the log can't be used as a better alternative, because factorials are most often used to compute values related 
to probabilities of choosing combinations of things.

A common thing to compute is probabilities that are based on factorials such as choosing the binomial coefficient (n k) = n! / (k!(n-k)!). Given this is a ratio of factorials then log(n k) = log(n!)-log(k!)-log((n-k)!) which is reliably computed using one of the various log factorial approximations. And if you do a lot of probability math it's generally best to do it in the log domain anyway (measuring probability in decibels) because it often involves extremely wide ranges of numbers less than 1, and so math precision will fall apart very quickly using common floating point representations if the log version is not used.

E.T.Jaynes was a famous mathematician and an expert in probability theory and I'd recommend his book "Probability Theory: The Logic of Science" as a very readable source on this topic and Bayesian reasoning and information theory using log probabilities.

Comment: If you can, you should point to a link to "log factorial approximations", since they are the most relevant in your answer to the question of calculating the factorial of a large number.

Comment: Some very readable pages of the preface of Jaynes's book are on [books.google.com/books?isbn=0521592712](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0521592712)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reduce function rather than explicit looping thus:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> mul = int.__mul__
>>> len(str(reduce(mul, range(2,100001), 1)))
456574
>>>
```

In Python 2 you need to use longs: `long.__mul__`, and `len(str(reduce(mul, range(2L,100001L), 1L)))`

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that factorial(100000) is [aproximately](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) 2.8242294080×10^456,573
That's why it's slow, it's huge.

Comment: Well, what i need is to get the length of the factorial, but before I can do that I need to generate the number (or at least that's what I think). len(str(factorial(100000))) does in fact return 456574, after roughly a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the gamma function (`math.gamma(x)`), but it would probably be faster to generate the factorial with a for loop

Comment: `math.gamma(100000)` unfortunately raises `OverflowError`; the function only works for values up to about 170.

Answer (score 0):

The slowdown in caused by a quadradic effect: as n gets larger you have to do more multiplications, but you also have to multiply larger numbers.

Finding a better algorithm won't be easy. You can try to exploit symmetries (as in FFT). It could also well pay to do multiplications in a different order, with intermediate results, such that you end up with multiplying only a few very big numbers at the end, but I haven't thought that to the end. In any case, you will have to find a *law* to exploit.

Look [here](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/conclusions.html) for further inspiration.

Comment: "It could also well pay to do multiplications in a different order, with intermediate results, such that you end up with multiplying only a few very big numbers at the end" I've tried that, in Haskell I get a **big** speedup from that, but my attempts in Python haven't made a big difference. Not sure why.

Comment: **Duh!** It's not the algorithm, it's the conversion to string that is so abominably slow!